# TemplateDoesNotExist at / pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 4.0.6 and I'm trying to host my web app at pythonanywhere.com but I get this error. I don't understand why it's happening, I looked at the settings.py and I didn't see anything wrong, all of the requirements are installed, the settings are looking alright  , the WSGI file is good I don't get why this error keeps popping up.

Here's my settings file:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/build')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here is where the error is occurring.

```py
def select_template(template_name_list, using=None):
    """
    Load and return a template for one of the given names.

    Try names in order and return the first template found.

    Raise TemplateDoesNotExist if no such template exists.
    """
    if isinstance(template_name_list, str):
        raise TypeError(
            "select_template() takes an iterable of template names but got a "
            "string: %r. Use get_template() if you want to load a single "
            "template by name." % template_name_list
        )

    chain = []
    engines = _engine_list(using)
    for template_name in template_name_list:
        for engine in engines:
            try:
                return engine.get_template(template_name)
            except TemplateDoesNotExist as e:
                chain.append(e)

    if template_name_list:
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist(", ".join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
    else:
        raise TemplateDoesNotExist("No template names provided")
```

It's saying that index.html is throwing the exception.

When I finished the website I ran npm run build and index.html is supposed to be my template file but for some reason it's not finding it I guess, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Provide the complete error. Does this happen only in production or also in development? Are you using Reactjs as your frontend?

Comment: what is the path to your templates? What is BASE_DIR?